# Pop alert when window/tab is not active

Tags: tabs, window, alert

I am trying for quite some time here but with no luck.

Do you have any idea how you can make a pop-up (alert) show, whenever the user changes tab/window from his browser?

So basically, when the user changes a window at his/her browser, the alert window will pop and the user will have to press the ok button to continue

This funcitonality is needed as I am creating an online tests site and I need to display the alert whenever the users will try to change tab/window

Comment: Please provide more information if you wish to receive a quality answer; as it stands you are being extremely vague. Also, given that you've spent quite some time with no luck then showing some of the effort would be desirable, this would enable you to point out where you're having trouble and allow others to pick up at that point.

Comment: @Mr., your name makes me sad every time I see it.

Comment: @Michael: So long as that's not indicative of my contributions, I can live with that.

Comment: @Mr. I edited to be as thorough as possible. As for the coding part, I just spend this time without concluding to anything. So it was basically a /code and erase/ procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `focus` and `blur` events on the window object (tabs are considered windows, too.) Try this out:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() { console.log('Window has focus'); });
window.addEventListener('blur', function() { console.log('Window lost focus'); });
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(window).focus(function() { console.log('Window has focus'); });
$(window).blur(function() { console.log('Window lost focus'); });
```

Also, be careful about using alerts in this manner. Many users may find it a bit annoying.

Comment: I know that alerts like that are annoying, but the purpose of the pages I am implementing it in is to NOT change your browser's tab. Focus and blur I guess the way to do it

Comment: I know it's not meant to change the tab, but alert's will bring focus to the page creating the alert. But, I trust you know what your doing because I have no idea what your building, and it may be critical that users don't leave the page (online testing?) I hope I answered your question though.

Comment: Yeah it will be an online testing so the users must stay on the current tab/window :)